# Using this or new in JS?

Tags: javascript, this, declare

I've got 3 codes :

```
var control = new Control();

function Control() {

   this.doSomethingElse = function() {...}
   this.doSomething = function () {
       control.doSomethingElse();
   }

}
```

Or

```
var control = new Control();

function Control() {
   var self = this;

   this.doSomethingElse = function() {...}
   this.doSomething = function () {
       self.doSomethingElse();
   }
}
```

Or

```
var control = Control();

function Control() {
   var self = this;

   this.doSomethingElse = function() {...}
   this.doSomething = function () {
       self.doSomethingElse();
   }

  return self;
}
```

Important : The function is a controller, and just declared once. Then I'm using "control"  everywhere in my code...

I was wondering if the control.doSomethingElse() was slow ?

In the end, what is the right thing to do and/or the fastest code in those exemple ?

Thanks !

Comment: #1 is wrong - an object should never internally use the name by which it is known outside.  That's what `this` (or `self`) is for.

Comment: @Alnitak: He's using a singleton object. Doesn't seem like he needs a constructor at all.

Comment: @squint true, but in that case he shouldn't use `this` in the assignments  - just `function Control() { return { doSomethingElse: ...,  doSomething: ... } }`

Answer (score 3):

The first is wrong - an object should never internally use the variable name by which it is known outside.  Other code could change that variable to point to something else, breaking this code.

The third is also wrong - when calling `Control()` without `new` the assignments to `this.foo` inside will end up getting attached to the global object (except in strict mode, where there's no implicit `this` on bare function calls, so the assignment to `this.doSomethingElse` tries to attach to `undefined`, causing a runtime error).

That only leaves the second as appropriate, but ultimately it's a question of correctness, not performance.

Answer (score 2):

Do not define methods in constructor - that means defining them every time an instance is created. Use `Control.prototype.foo = function() {}` instead. Also you do not need to `return this` if you're using new operator - that's the whole point of `new` operator.

The recommended approach is this:

```
function MyClass(param1) {
    // Here we're changing the specific instance of an object
    this.property1 = param1;
}
// Prototype will be shared with all instances of the object
// any modifications to prototype WILL be shared by all instances
MyClass.prototype.printProperty1 = function() {
    console.log(this.property1);
}

var instance = new MyClass("Hello world!");
instance.printProperty1(); // Prints hello world
```

To understand this code, you need to understand javascript's prototype-based inheritance model. When you create instance of MyClass, you get a new object that inherits any properties present in `MyClass.prototype`. [Read more about it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

---

Also I wonder:

> The function is a controller, and just declared once.

If you're not using this multiple times, you don't need to create something like class. You can do this instead:

```
var control = {doSomething:function() { ... }};
```

I assume you are used to Java, where everything must be a class, whether it makes sense or not. Javascript is different, you can also make single objects or functions as you need.

Comment: There are many perfectly good reasons to define methods in the constructor, and a singleton is one of them, since there's no overhead in having multiple copies of the same functions being created over and over.  Being dogmatic about it does more harm than good.

Comment: @Alnitak I mentioned how singletons are defined in Javascript. And I am not being dogmatic - I mentioned the reason I discourage OP's approach, it's up to him to make decision.

Comment: Hello Everyone, thanks for your answers, yes, I was born with java, and like clean code, But, what about performance ?  which one of the answers has the fasted execution / access ?

Comment: @alexino2 As Alnitak pointed out, if you're creating only one instance it does not matter. But in general, when making Javascript pseudoclasses, do not define methods in the constructor. Reasons are described in my answer.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato Yes, it's a Singleton :) the whole point in the end is to know if "self = this" is acting like prototype, or is it a new copy of "this" ? or if it is faster to use "control" instead ?

Comment: @alexino2 no, `this` only refers to the current instance, so it's nothing like the prototype.  In any case, as I said in my answer, your first and third code examples aren't good code anyway.  #1 violates encapsulation, and #3 isn't legal code.